# I cant seem to use dependency injection in WinRT BackgroundTask

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, background, windows-runtime

I am implementing IBackgroundTask in a Windows Runtime Component and I'd like to inject a logger dependency into it but the application exits when it calls the background task. It won't even enter the constructor. I'm using Ninject as a DI container and have no problems using it anywhere else in the app.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
private readonly ILog _logger;

public BackroundTask(ILog logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        try
        {
            // do something here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log the error with injected logger...
            logger.ErrorFormat("{0}Error in QueueTimer {1}{0}",
                Environment.NewLine, ex.ToString());
        }

        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

I've had no success with anything I've tried and now just log on the OnComplete method in the calling .cs file.

Comment: ILOG has to be compiled to support WinRT.  What exactly is the error?

Comment: On an unrelated note, `async void` should generally be avoided except for event handlers. You may well have a valid reason for doing this, but something to consider if you don't.

Comment: I am using an async call that posts data back to a server, then I need to log the success or failure of the post.

Comment: ILog is compiled as a windows runtime component. The error in the Event Log is: Activation of the app a.Winrt.Ui_tjekt9a7fmk0j!App for the Windows.BackgroundTasks contract failed with error: Not implemented

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience with creating Windows Store applications, you must supply a default constructor for background tasks; any other constructors won't be called.

Hopefully I'm wrong about this, though; it would be practical to be able to pass background tasks' dependencies in, but I'm not sure if it makes sense since your own code might not even be running when the task starts. I think the only way to communicate between your program and the task is by using permanent storage.